# Is Perseverance really nicknamed Perky?

Tags: perseverance

[A MSN article](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/technology/nasas-perseverance-fails-to-collect-its-first-mars-samples/ar-AAN7Bt4) states :

> Perseverance, nicknamed Perky

Is this nickname actually used for Perseverance? By whom? Do the people at NASA colloquially call the rover Perky?

Comment: I would have thought Percy would might have been a better contraction of Perseverance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common nickname is certainly Percy, not Perky. I did find a single article on [nasa.gov](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/mission/status/333/speaking-percys-language-how-to-talk-so-perseverance-will-listen/) that uses the name Percy, none with Perky.

In addition, [the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perseverance_(rover)) article references Percy, not Perky. I can tell you many scientist accounts on Twitter reference Percy as well, as listed below. I have literally never heard Perseverance referred to as Perky until this question. Looking around a bit, it seems like it is occasionally used, but never by those who are the most informed.

From Twitter, here is a list of scientists, NASA accounts, major space journalists, or otherwise good sources of information referring to Perseverance as Percy.

- [Popular unofficial account @PercyRover](https://twitter.com/PercyRover)
- https://twitter.com/haygenwarren/status/1437806572101464064?s=20
- https://twitter.com/NASA_SLS/status/1426279900911226882?s=20
- https://twitter.com/tanyaofmars/status/1423983307780411392?s=20
- https://twitter.com/starstryder/status/1423294601016659973?s=20
- https://twitter.com/volcanopele/status/1410624657229631490?s=20
- https://twitter.com/airandspace/status/1403776628455522307?s=20
- https://twitter.com/planet4589/status/1393332349715329026?s=20
- https://twitter.com/scifri/status/1385656719573929987?s=20
- https://twitter.com/NASAGoddard/status/1371113899324497920?s=20
- https://twitter.com/HiRISE/status/1367587573443358722?s=20

I haven't found a single one referencing Perky. Note that there are 3 official NASA twitter accounts in this list, and I didn't spend too long putting it together.

Comment: Do you have examples of scientist accounts on Twitter that reference Percy?

Comment: Added a bunch of examples on Twitter, hopefully that should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Daily Mail's [Perseverance takes its first color pictures of Mars: Incredible NASA images show rover being lowered onto the red planet after its 239-million mile journey through space](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-9279433/NASA-shares-new-images-Perseverance-Mars-showing-rover-hanging-curly-electrical-cords.html):

> The American space agency shared an image shot by the sky crane that shows Perseverance, nicknamed Perky, slung beneath and attached to mechanical bridles – moments before making landfall.

and later

> The image also captured the dusty and rocky Mars surface below, exciting NASA of what possibilities are ahead of its beloved Perky.

So you could some what assume they do indeed use Perky as a nickname publicly

Comment: Eh, that isn't exactly what I would call a primary source... There might be some who use it, but it isn't common...